# MySQL Error 1146 and 1050 - Table does not exists and Table already exists

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, mysql-python

I've been migrating my database from the default Django sqlite3 to MySql but while running this command -

```
py manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

I get the  following error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'blogue_test.blogueapp_category' doesn't exist")
```

This is how I create the SQL Table manually

```
 CREATE TABLE blogueapp_category(
-> id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-> name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
-> PRIMARY KEY (id)
-> );
```

Then re-run the same migrate command and it shows me the table already exists?

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'blogueapp_category' already exists")
```

This is my Django models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('category-list', kwargs={'cats': self.name})
```

EDIT:
Error after running 'migrate'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 73, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'blogue_test.blogueapp_category' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thesh\Desktop\Current Project\vert - Copy\blogue\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()
  File "C:\Users\thesh\Desktop\Current Project\vert - Copy\blogue\manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 75, in handle
self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\thesh\Desktop\Current Project\vert - Copy\blogue\blogue\urls.py", line 14, in <module>
path('', include('blogueApp.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\thesh\Desktop\Current Project\vert - Copy\blogue\blogueApp\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
from .views import AddCommentView, HomeView, ArticleDetailView, AddPostView, UpdatePostView, DeletePostView, AddCategoryView, CategoryView, LikeView
  File "C:\Users\thesh\Desktop\Current Project\vert - Copy\blogue\blogueApp\views.py", line 5, in <module>
from .forms import EditForm, PostForm, CommentForm
  File "C:\Users\thesh\Desktop\Current Project\vert - Copy\blogue\blogueApp\forms.py", line 8, in <module>
for item in choices:
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 280, in __iter__
self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 140, in __iter__
return compiler.results_iter(tuple_expected=True, chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1130, in results_iter
results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in _execute
with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 73, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\thesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
```

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'blogue_test.blogueapp_category' doesn't exist")

forms.py

```
from .models import Post, Category, Comment

choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name')
choice_list = []

for item in choices:
    choice_list.append(item)

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'author', 'category', 'article_image','body')

        widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Title'}),
        'author': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','value':'', 'id':'author_id', 'type':'hidden'}),
        'category': forms.Select(choices=choice_list, attrs={'class':'form-select'}),
        'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Main Content'}),
    }
```

I am merely a beginner in this and have been stuck with this same error for the past 2 days, even tried doing it in PostgreSQL but resulted in the same.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you create the table manually when the migrate command will create the table for you?

Comment: Exactly where I am stuck at cause after running the migrate command it shows the error - Table doesn't exist??

Comment: You need to remove the table and add the full traceback from the migration error to your question. It's possible you have a query being executed when your app is loaded

Comment: I didn't get you? Sorry, I'm just a beginner at this.

Comment: Delete the table you created manually, run the migrate command again, add the __full__ output from the command to your question

Comment: That’s not the full error, can you add what follows “The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:”

Comment: Made the required changes.

Comment: On line 8 of `blogue\blogueApp\forms.py` you loop over a queryset on load of your app causing a query to execute, this is causing you your issue. You need to remove this so that you don't execute queries on load. Add this section of your code if you don't know how to remove it?

Comment: Added the forms.py section

Comment: Where are you using `choice_list` in your forms, can you show the form/field where it's used? A `forms.ModelChoiceField` would probably work instead?

Comment: I'm using that so the user can add new categories and select one while uploading a post. Added that section too in the new edit.

Comment: Just delete the whole `choice_list` section/variable from your forms. Choices for a ForeignKey in a ModelForm update naturally anyway and adding choices to a field through a widget doesn't make much sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241603/discussion-between-not-a-great-programmer-and-iain-shelvington).

Answer (score -1):

2 steps you can follow to migrate fresh table:

1. First, delete the manually created table.
2. Second, while defining the model please follow the db_name in your meta classname of model:

   ```
   class Meta:
        db_table = 'x_claims_group_health'
   ```

Comment: Am I supposed to add this under class Category(models.Model): ?

Comment: not under just inside the class model